# How to paste image from clipboard to Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, clipboard, office-interop

I have copied an image from a word document to the clipboard programmatically.

I want to paste that image into another word file using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word for word reference.

Here is the code :

```
foreach (Words.InlineShape shape in document.InlineShapes)
{
    if (shape != null)
    {
        if (shape.Type == Words.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
        {
             shape.Select();
             app.Selection.CopyAsPicture();
             Words.Document doc = app.Documents.Add();

             System.Drawing.Image img = null;
             if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
             {
                  img = Clipboard.GetImage();
                  IDataObject idata = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Produce some your code how you try to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than work with the clipboard directly, you can simply paste it back using Word's own paste function. For example:

```
doc.Content.Paste();
```

But first ask yourself whether you really need to use the clipboard at all. Using the clipboard means that you'll leave a large picture on the clipboard (wasting memory) unless you clean it up, and it also means that you lose the original content of the clipboard, which might upset your users. Consider using the `FormattedText` of the `Range` instead:

```
targetRange.FormattedText = sourceRange.FormattedText
```

The `FormattedText` property copies all the text *and formatting* and that includes any embedded fields, tables, pictures, etc. (You need to start with the range that includes the anchor point for the original picture). You can get that range for an `InlineShape` via the `Range` property. (For a floating `Shape` you'd use the `Anchor` property).

Comment: -Thank you so much for your help.The FormattedText is working out.Just a little problem with the range I think.When i try to copy two images the previous image is overwritten.So how can i help out with that?

Comment: It sounds like you're pasting into a range, then pasting into the same range. Remember that when you paste, the selection expands to include the pasted content, so if you then use that same range as the paste target for the next paste, you'll overwrite everything. Try collapsing the range before you paste (`range.Collapse(wdCollapseEnd)`).

Comment: Thank you so much.I got the proper answer.