# Paste PictureBox.Image into Word (Interop)

Tags: c#, image, picturebox, word-interop

Is there a way to paste the image (eg. from a PictureBox) directly into a Word Shape?
I'm currently using Clipboard to copy then Clipboard.SetImage(Image);  But was hoping to do it directly without the Clipboard.  This link [How to paste image from clipboard to Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031538/how-to-paste-image-from-clipboard-to-word) references using the Range.FormattedText, but I'm not sure how to make the Image into a FormattedText?

Here's my code using the Clipboard:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape s in wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
{
    if (s.Title.Equals("WordImage", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
         Word.Range range = s.Anchor;
         Clipboard.SetImage(myPictureBox.Image);
         range.Paste();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to paste the image (eg. from a PictureBox) directly
> into a Word Shape? [#word-interop]

Define **"directly"**. If you mean **"is there a property of type `Shape` or `InlineShape` we can set an instance of dotnet class `Image`?"** then the answer is **NO**.

Both `Shape` and `InlineShape` types do not expose any method to pass argument in or property to set dotnet `image` object or data of `image` object.

Instances of dotnet class `Image` should be saved into a file then added into word document with `Shapes.AddPicture()` method, or saved into clipboard then pasted into word document with `Range.Paste()` method. There is no other way.

There is a property `string Shape.RTF`, which is set-only, intuitively suggests to set rtf data of an image. But the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.rtf?view=word-pia) says it is *"Reserved for internal use."*.

**Conclusion**

Dotnet `Image` object cannot be inserted into Word document **"directly"**. It canbe inserted via a file or clipboard.